# How to Delete Newline at End of GtkTextBuffer

Tags: c++, gtk

So I am working on making a more or less fixed size GtkTextBuffer (and if there is a better way to do this please let me know) and I am using marks to divide the buffer into "entries". Then using those marks I delete a section of the buffer from the start iter to the iter at the appropriate mark.

The issue with all of this is that it leaves a newline at the end of the buffer which I am unable to figure out how to delete. Anybody have experience with this or have any ideas on how to delete the newline?

Here is my current code:

```
// markName is a c string and textBuffEntries is an int
// keeping track of how many entries there are in the buffer
snprintf(markName, 9, "%d", textBuffEntries);
if(allMarksPopulated) {
   neo_debug(func_mask, "Deleting: %s", markName);
   gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(buffer, &startIter);
  gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_mark(buffer, &markIter,
        gtk_text_buffer_get_mark(buffer, markName));
  gtk_text_buffer_delete(buffer, &startIter, &markIter);
  gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_line(buffer, &markIter, 1);
  gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(buffer, &startIter);
  gtk_text_buffer_delete(buffer, &startIter, &markIter);
}
neo_debug(func_mask, "textBuffEntries: %d", textBuffEntries);

// Now write the data to the buffer
gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(buffer, &endIter);
gtk_text_buffer_insert (buffer, &endIter, 
      msg_str.c_str(), 
      msg_str.length());

snprintf(markName, 9, "%d", textBuffEntries);
gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(buffer, &endIter),
gtk_text_buffer_create_mark(buffer, markName,
             &endIter,
             true);
msg_str = "\n";
gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(buffer, &endIter);
gtk_text_buffer_insert (buffer, &endIter, 
      msg_str.c_str(), 
      msg_str.length());

if(!allMarksPopulated && MAX_LINES == textBuffEntries)
{
   allMarksPopulated = true;
}

if(MAX_LINES == textBuffEntries)
{
   textBuffEntries = 0;
} else {
   textBuffEntries++;
}
```

Comment: What's your specific purpose? It seems like there are much better ways to display a divided entry-based system.

Comment: The goal of the system is to display text alerts to the user, status messages to keep the user updated of things happening on other tabs in the system and events external to the GUI that are happening. The goal of the entry based system is to keep the size of this alerts log to a reasonable size as the system may be running for months at a time.

Comment: Couldn't you use something like a ListBox?

Comment: I fixed it, I was being dumb about where the newline was getting inserted so I changed it to prepend the insertion string instead of appending it.

Comment: You can post that as an answer to help others in the future. SO aims to be a programming encyclopedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comment above:

I fixed it, I was being dumb about where the newline was getting inserted so I changed it to prepend the insertion string instead of appending it. So that when each "bookmark" section is deleted there is a clean line ending.